# What is the best way to store many images without having a performance issue?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I'm making a puzzle game based on **Reactnative**. This game contains more than **2000 images**. Now what I do is convert the images to **base64 string** and store the data in a **expo SQLite** database. Other options I'm not sure if i should choose is to use **Firebase** or just drop the images into the **assets folder**.

The question is **What is the best way to store many images without having a performance issue?** I haven't had any performance issue yet but I have a bad fill to store a huge string in the database.

Comment: I would recommend a CDN or even firebase storage seems ok. That way you could fetch and download the images as and when required and your app is not bloated with a lot of assets.

Comment: "Performance issue" is too broad, what are you optimizing for?  If you store everything locally, it'll load faster, but take more space.

Comment: @sushrut619 Thank you for your reply. I will use the cloud method. It seems to be the most common practice.

Comment: The application size became too big and I was advised by a friend that storing images within the database is not a good practice. Also storing the images in assets folder looks very primitive for me. @Abe